# Matplotlib Quiver plot matching key label color with arrow color

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, python3.6. I am trying to create some quiverkeys for a quiver plot but having a hard time getting the label colors to match certain arrows. Below is a simplified version of the code to show the issue.  When I use the same color (0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0 ) for a vector at (1,1) and as 'labelcolor' of a quiverkey I see 2 different colors.

```
q=plt.quiver([1, 2,], [1, 1],
             [[49],[49]],
             [0],
             [[(0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 1.0 )],
             [(0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0 )]],
             angles=[[45],[90]])
plt.quiverkey(q, .5, .5, 7, r'vector2', labelcolor=(0.3, 0.1, .2, 1),
              labelpos='S', coordinates = 'figure')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly you meant to be using the `color` argument of `quiver` to set the actual colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q=plt.quiver([1, 2,], [1, 1], [5,0], [5,5],
             color=[(0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 1.0 ), (0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0 )])
plt.quiverkey(q, .5, .5, 7, r'vector2', labelcolor=(0.3, 0.1, .2, 1),
                      labelpos='S', coordinates = 'figure')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Else, the `C` argument is interpreted as the values to map to colors according to the default colormap. Since you only have two arrows, only the first two values from the 8 numbers in the array given to the `C` argument are taken into account. But the colormap normalization uses all of those values, such that it ranges between 0.1 and 1.0. The call

```
q=plt.quiver([1, 2,], [1, 1], [5,0], [5,5],
             [(0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 1.0 ), (0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0 )])
```

is hence equivalent to

```
q=plt.quiver([1, 2,], [1, 1], [5,0], [5,5],
             [0.6, 0.8], norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0.1, vmax=1))
```

resulting in the first arrows color to be the value of 0.6 in the viridis colormap normalized between 0.1 and 1.0, and the second arrow to 0.8 in that colormap.

This becomes apparent if we add `plt.colorbar(q, orientation="horizontal")`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I see what you are saying. I think I used C over color because it allowed me to pass in a 2D array of colors. My plot has multiple vectors at each X,Y. And each of those has a different color. I wanted a key for one particular colored vector across all the groups. I stripped that down to one vector per origin to make it simpler to convey...but this answer has helped me see the normalization step and default colormap. Need to play with it more. Thanks!