# How to label multiple arrows in the same quiver plot using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a visualization script for a linear algebra class at the university and I am trying to show multiple vectors using the quiver function in python. I am trying to plot vectors coming from a 2x2 matrix in one quiver function, however, now that I am trying to label them I would like to access each vector individually.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[1,3], [2,2]])
# create figure
fig = plt.figure()
# creates variable containing current figure
ax = fig.gca()

baseArrow = ax.quiver(*origin, A[0,:], A[1,:], color=['r','g']',  angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1) 

ax.quiverkey(baseArrow,.85,.85,0.8,'i-hat',labelcolor='k',labelpos='S', coordinates = 'figure')

# display grid
plt.grid()
# display figure
plt.show()
```

This alows me to label the first vector with the respective color (red). Now what I would like to do is label the second vector in green with a different label?
Maybe something like:

```
ax.quiverkey(baseArrow**[2]**,.85,.85,0.8,'i-hat',labelcolor='k',labelpos='S', coordinates = 'figure')
```

Is there any way to pull out each vector by itself or would it be better to plot them individually instead of as a vector? I looked at the following question but it doesn't really solve my issue. [Matplotlib Quiver plot matching key label color with arrow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871552/matplotlib-quiver-plot-matching-key-label-color-with-arrow-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that the `quiver` function is better suited/intended to plot numerous vectors as you would find in a graph depicting magnetic forces, vortices (sic) or gradients (see `meshgrid` for example). And it's API reflects that, in that it accepts end and start coordinates separately: i.e. you need to split the components of your vectors as you have done above.
May I suggest you look into the `plot` or `arrow` functions which will give you greater control over your visualization (e.g. vector-independent labels) and will also provide greater clarity in your code, as you will be able to declare vectors (as np.arrays of course) and use them directly. 
Finally note that you can obtain fig and ax in one call: `fib, ax = plt.subplots()`. 
Hope this helps!